# "no longer assumed not endotherms" = endotherms or not endotherms?

Tags: sentence-meaning, writing, academic-writing

I'm practicing integrated writing with a friend of mine, and I wrote a sentence that she found confusing, which is:

> ..., the writer discusses the fact that dinosaurs were no longer assumed not endotherms. The lecturer in
> the listening passage disagrees. She believes that dinosaurs are not endotherms and attacks each of the claims
> made in the reading.

Here is the comment of my friend:

> You are saying that the article no longer assumes dinosaurs as endotherms and again the listening also believes that
> dinosaurs are not endotherms.
> I think the article assumes dinosaurs as endotherms and the lecture refutes it.

So, **no longer assumes dinosaurs as not endotherms** is it means that they are **endotherms** or **not endotherms**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is confusing, and unnecessarily so.

The basic structure "assumed {noun}" is somewhat odd.  It is common enough to use "assumed {adjective}", but I'd interpret "dinosaurs are assumed endotherms" to mean "Dinosaurs are assumed to be endotherms" or "People assume that dinosaurs are endotherms".

If we now look at the actual phrase, it would have to be understood as:

> Dinosaurs were no longer assumed to be non-endotherms.

or

> People no longer assumed that dinosaurs were non-endotherms.

Why do you write "not endotherms" when there is a good word "ectotherms"

> People no longer assumed that dinosaurs were ectotherms.

You claim that the writer is saying that dinosaurs could have been endo- or ectotherms, and people do not assume one or the other.

However the phrasing is very confusing, and needs to be re-written in quite a fundamental way: Try to avoid negatives and passive voice, and it will make your writing clearer.